# Class with 2 atributes to convert intenger to roman in python

Tags: python, class, constructor

I´ve to create a class with a constructor in python. This constructor has to receive one number and save this number in 2 atributes. The first one will keep the number as an intenger and the second one while convert the number to roman and save it as a string
any help?
thank you all

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class RomanConversion():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n;
        self.roman = self.convert_to_roman(n)
        
    def convert_to_roman(self, n):
        return "roman"
```

Comment: YES! It´s really helpfull!!!!!!!!!! My problem was I were only able to obtain the result receiven both atributes normal and roman but I really think that this is what I were asked for!